# Pear Orchard (word problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A farmer has $70$ acres on which to plant a pear orchard. three neighboring farms with similar soil conditions already established orchards. one of these orchards has $250$ tress planted per acre yielding, on average, $525$ pears per tree. Another $280$ trees per acre, yielding $480$ pears per tree, while the third with $350$ tress per acre yields only $375$ pears pear tree.

Based on the data, derive equations for both the yield per tree and the yield per acre as functions of $x$, the tree density(trees/acre). What density of planting is expected to yield no pears? 
What density does your model suggest will produce the maximum yield per acre.

The average weight of a pear is approximately $1/2$-pound. Using appropriate transformation write an equation expressing the total yield from the farmer's $70$ acres, measured in tons(rather than pears), as a function of the number of tress per acre( NOTE: $1$ u.s ton=$2,000$ pounds).

**the equation i got for the first part is. y= -1.5x+900**

**when the density of planting is 600 it is expected to yield no pears**

Comment: the equation i got for the first part is. y= -1.5x+900

Comment: when the density of planting is 600 it is expected to yield no pears

Comment: when the density is 0 the model suggest it will produce the maximum yield per acre

Comment: How do i come up with an equation that is in tons rather than pears?

Comment: First, you should put these comments in the body of the question. Second, you are incorrect about the maximum yield per acre: when the density is $0$, you get the maximum yield per *tree*, but you have no trees, so the yield per acre is zero. The yield per acre is $x$ times the yield per tree, i.e. $x(-1.5x+900)$.

Comment: okay i will . but is everything else correct so far?

Comment: Looks OK otherwise, yes.

Comment: am i suppose t find the H by using the formula. -b/2a

Comment: That's a valid way to do it. Note that this is the density which results in the maximum yield. You have to plug that back into the expression for the yield to get the maximum yield itself.

Comment: -900/2(-1.5) = 300.

Comment: so now i have to plug the (300) into the equation y=-1.5x+900

Comment: You would need to plug back into $y=x(-1.5x+900)$ if you were asked for the maximum yield, but it looks like you were not.

Comment: yeah because it asked me the density that would result the maximum yield per acre.

Comment: so 300 density gives you the highest yield per acre

Comment: Now i dont know where to start to find the equation expressing the total yield from the farmer's in tons rather than pears

Comment: Hint: 4000 pears=1 ton. So you should either divide or multiply by 4000; which one is it?

Comment: you should divide by 4000

Comment: im still stuck on how to write the equation